# Implementation of a shift operation for Set in JavaScript that emulates the one for arrays

Tags: javascript, set

I discovered that the JavaScript sets are ordered but don't offer a method to take the first element out of the set. For the arrays this operation exists and it's called shift.

A very basic implementation can be written in this way:

```
function shiftSet(s) {
    let res;
    for (let v of s) {
        res= v;
        break;
    }
    s.delete(res);
    return res;
}
```

Do you see a better way to write it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first element of a set can be retrieved by calling the `next()` method on an iterator of the [`Set` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Since you’re using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement, such an iterator is already used under the hood (the same is true for `forEach` and the spread operator).

Apart from that, there is no reason to shorten the variable names like you did. Generally, it makes code less readable. Call it `set`, not `s`.

Your function can be rewritten like this:

```
function shiftSet(set) {
    const firstValue = set.values().next().value;
    set.delete(firstValue);
    return firstValue;
}
```

Comment: @Blindman67 This is not the case. [`values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/values) creates a new iterator, not a new array. Also, in your solution, [`[Symbol.iterator]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/@@iterator) will return the same iterator. Our solutions are virtually the same and where posted at the same time. :)

Comment: Yes just realized that

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is via the iterator function.

```
function shifySet(set) {
    const first = set[Symbol.iterator]().next().value;
    set.delete(first);
    return first;
}
```

I was going to check if there was an item, but it seams pointless. Works the same as your function shifts the first entry, returning it, or undefined if not found.

I would make a slight change to your version

```
function shiftSet(set) {
    for (const res of set) {
        set.delete(res);
        return res
    }
}
```